# heroku css stylesheet won't display

Tags: css, heroku

i have just deployed my rails application but the css stylesheet wont appear

I'm calling the stylesheet as follows:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'layout' %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the obvious one is that the stylesheet exists in your directory at:

```
public/stylesheets/layout.css
```

Also, if you scaffold'd your models/views etc, make sure you don't have another layout file with the controller name in:

```
app/views/layouts/xxxscaffoldname.html.erb
```

cause the screws up your css layout rendering if you want to show the application.html.erb(or whatever you called it) layout only.